# Why do some values not function for my code?

Tags: swift, integer

I am trying to create an app that will have the user input a number and the app will determine if it is prime or not. Here is my code:

```
var arr: [Int] = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
let text = Int(textField.text!)!
for x in arr {
    if text == 1 {
        iLabel.text = "NOT PRIME!"
    }
    else if x == 2 || x == 3 || x == 5 || x == 7 {
        iLabel.text = "IT'S PRIME!"
    }
    else if text % x == 0 {
        iLabel.text = "NOT PRIME!"
        break
    }
    else if text % x != 0 {
        iLabel.text = "IT'S PRIME!"
        break
    }
}
```

For the most part, this works. However, when I set variable "text" to equal something like 82, the result is "IT'S PRIME!" despite it being evenly divisible by 2...can anyone explain the flaw in my code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if text == 1 else if x == 2 else if text % x == 0
     ^               ^                ^
```

it will trigger `x=2` and set "IT'S PRIME` before it gets to the modulo/remainder check, which it will then skip. It will trigger the same thing at loop 3, 5, 7.

82 is not divisible by 8 or 9 so it won't happen to trigger the remainder check at the end of the loop and accidentally output the correct value, leaving "IT'S PRIME" in the output box, without actually checking whether it's prime.